# onblocked fired when trying to open db with higher version number

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

I am creating indexedDB database `products_db`.

- `onload` adding objectStore `products_os` to db.
- fetching data from server and adding data to `products_os`.
- displaying data in UI.
- `onclick` of *add* button, trying to open db with higher version number and creating a new objectStore `cart_os`. **This is where it does not work as expected.**

---

**Current Behaviour:**

- When I open chrome browser in incognito mode and load my *index.html* file in a tab, one table row is displayed in the UI, but in the `Application` tab of `Developer Tools` there in no `product_db` database in `indexedDB`.
- On clicking the add button, an alert of `onblocked` event as given in
  `function addCartData(e) {` pops up. ( There is no other tab with this site open! ). After closing the popup, now a click on same add button does nothing.
- Now, if I refresh the page with *cmd + shift + r*, a new row is appended to the table. It has a total of two rows now. On every refresh, a new row is appended. Previous point is true for all the add buttons that are in the UI, click on any one will trigger the alert and then all are rendered useless.(no popup onclick).
- If I clear the storage and then do *cmd + shift + r*, again I get only one row in the UI.

**Expected Behaviour:**

- indexedDB in *Application* tab of *Developer tools* should not be empty. Instead it should be populated with `db` and `objectStore`.
- On Refresh, without clearing the storage, only one row should be
  displayed every time.
- `onclick` of add button, a db should open with new version number and objectStore `cart_os` should be added to it. So that later I can use `cart_os` for `read/write` transaction.

---

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Product Table</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id='idb-table' style="width=100%" />
  </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
// Create an instance of a db object for us to store the open database in
let db;

window.onload = function() {
  // Open our database; it is created if it doesn't already exist
  let request = window.indexedDB.open('products_db', 1);

  // onerror handler signifies that the database didn't open successfully
  request.onerror = function() {
    console.log('Database failed to open');
  }

  // onsuccess handler signifies that the database opened successfully
  request.onsuccess = function() {
    console.log('Database opened successfully');

    // Store the opened database object in the db variable. This is used a lot below
    db = request.result;

    // Run the fetchProducts() function to fetch data from external API 
    fetchProducts();
  }

  // Setup the database tables if this has not already been done
  request.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
    // Grab a reference to the opened database
    let db = e.target.result;

    // Create an objectStore to store our products in (basically like a single table)
    // including a auto-incrementing key
    let objectStore = db.createObjectStore('products_os', {keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true});

    // Define what data items the objectStore will contain
    objectStore.createIndex('title', 'title', {unique: false});
    objectStore.createIndex('price', 'price', {unique: false});
    objectStore.createIndex('inStock', 'inStock', {unique: false});

  }

  function fetchProducts() {
    let product1 = fetch('http://localhost:3001/location/pathname') // see product.json file
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        addData(response);
      })
  }

  function addData(value) {
    // open a read/write db transaction, ready for adding the data
    let transaction = db.transaction(['products_os'], 'readwrite');

    // call an object store that's already been added to the database
    let objectStore = transaction.objectStore('products_os');

    let newItem = {
      title: value.title,
      price: value.sellingPrice,
      inStock: value.inStock,
    };

    // Make a request to add our newItem object to the object store
    var request = objectStore.add(newItem);

    transaction.oncomplete = function() {
      console.log('Transaction completed: database modification finished.');

      // update the display of data to show the newly added item, by running displayData() again.
      displayData();
    }

    transaction.onerror = function() {
      console.log('Transaction not opened due to error');
    };
  }

  function displayData() {
    // Open our object store and then get a cursor - which iterates through all the
    // different data items in the store
    let objectStore = db.transaction('products_os').objectStore('products_os');

    objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(e) {
      // Get a reference to the cursor
      let cursor = e.target.result;

      // Get a reference to table
      let table = document.querySelector('#idb-table');

      // If there is still another data item to iterate through, keep running this code
      if(cursor) {
        // Insert into table,
        // structure the HTML fragment, and append it inside the table
        let tableRow = document.createElement('tr');
        for (let val in cursor.value) {
          if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(cursor.value, val)) {
            if (val !== 'id') {
              let td = document.createElement('td');
              tableRow.appendChild(td);
              td.textContent = cursor.value[val];
            }
          }
        }
        let td = document.createElement('td');
        td.setAttribute('align', 'center');
        let addButton = document.createElement('button');
        td.appendChild(addButton);
        addButton.textContent = 'Add';
        addButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
          addCartData(e);
        })
        tableRow.appendChild(td);
        table.appendChild(tableRow);

        // Iterate to the next item in the cursor
        cursor.continue();
      }
    }
  }

  function addCartData(e) {
    // Open the db with higher version number
    let req = window.indexedDB.open('products_db', 2);

    req.onerror = function() {
      console.log('Database failed to open');
    }

    req.onsuccess = function() {
      console.log('Database opened successfully');

      // Store the opened database object in the db variable. This is used a lot below
      db = req.result;
    }

    req.onblocked = function(event) {
      // If some other tab is loaded with the database, then it needs to be closed
      // before we can proceed.
      alert("Please close all other tabs with this site open!");
    };

    req.onupgradeneeded = function(e){
      // Grab a reference to the opened database
      let db = e.target.result;

      // Create a cart objectStore to store our information added to the cart
      let cartStore = db.createObjectStore('cart_os', {keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true});

      // Define what data items the cart objectStore will contain
      cartStore.createIndex('title', 'title', {unique: false});
      cartStore.createIndex('price', 'price', {unique: false});
    }
  }
```

styles.css

```
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
} 

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}   

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
} 

tr:last-child {
  text-align: center!important;
}
```

product.json

```
{
   "title": "Newhide Designer",
   "productDescription": "",
   "sellingPrice": 119,
   "inStock": true,
}
```

---

**EDIT**

[objectStore `products_os` was never added to db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOtjr.png)

I get error `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'transaction' on 'IDBDatabase': One of the specified object stores was not found.` at line *207* as shown in the image.

onupgradeneeded_version1:

```
function onupgradeneeded_version1(e) {
  // Grab a reference to the opened database
  let db = e.target.result;

  // Create an objectStore to store our products in (basically like a single table)
  // including a auto-incrementing key
  let objectStore = db.createObjectStore('products_os', {keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true});

  // Define what data items the objectStore will contain
  objectStore.createIndex('title', 'title', {unique: false});
  objectStore.createIndex('price', 'price', {unique: false});
  objectStore.createIndex('inStock', 'inStock', {unique: false});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are a ton of suggestions I have for how to improve this code, but to get straight to the point, I think the problem stems from the fact that you open a database connection initially, and keep it open (indefinitely), and then in your click handler, open a second database version with a higher version number, which if clicked, occurs while the initial database connection is still open.

I suggest encapsulating the `indexedDB.open => db` logic in a promise. This will make the code easier to read and write. Then I suggest changing how you use that promise.

Here is kind of what I am thinking:

```
function open(name, version, onupgradeneeded) {
  return new Promise(function executor(resolve, reject) {
    const request = indexeDB.open(name, version);
    request.onsuccess = function(event) { resolve(request.result); };
    request.onerror = function(event) { reject(request.result); };
    request.onblocked = function(event) { console.debug('blocked indefinitely'); };
    request.onupgradeneeded = onupgradeneeded;
  });
}

async function fetch_product() {
  const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/location/pathname');
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
}

function add_product(db, data) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    const transaction = db.transaction(..., 'readwrite');
    transaction.oncomplete = resolve;
    transaction.onerror = reject;
    const store = transaction.objectStore(...);
    store.put(data);
  });
}

function get_products(db) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    const transaction = db.transaction(...);
    const store = transaction.objectStore(...);
    const request = store.getAll();
    request.onsuccess = function(event) {
      const products_array = request.result;
      resolve(products_array);
    };
    request.onerror = function(event) {
      reject(request.error);
    };
  });
}

function render_product(product) {
  const table = document.getElementById('table-id');

  // create rows and all that.
  // and append
  button.onclick = handle_click;
}

async function handle_click(event) {

  // Based on what was clicked, find and build the product data object
  // event.target is the button
  const row = event.target.closest('tr');
  const name = row.querySelector('td.namecolumn').textContent;
  // etc
  const product = {
    name: name
  };

  const db = await open(name, version2, onupgradeneeded_for_version2);
  await add_product(db, product);
  db.close();
}

async function onload() {
  const product = await fetch_product();
  const db = await open(name, version, onupgradeneeded_version1);
  await add_product(db, product);

  const products = await get_products(db);

  // we are done with the db now
  db.close();

  // print out product data
  for(const product of products) {
    render_product(product);
  }  
}
```

Comment: I wrote a function for `onupgradeneeded_version1`, that is exactly the same as RHS of `request.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {` from the question. In the _script.js_ of question it was getting fired and thus creating an objectStore **products_os** in db. But if the extend the same logic with the solution, get `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'transaction' on 'IDBDatabase': One of the specified object stores was not found.`.  Please see **EDIT** in question.

Comment: Why have you done `async function onload {`? Why is `async` there?

Comment: Specifying async in a function definition allows you to use await within its body.